# Get var from url codeigniter+datatables plugin

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, get, datatables

I'm using the [DataTables](https://datatables.net/) plugin for paginate the query on DB. The problem came when i want get the parameter '`draw`' (for example) from the url:

```
http://localhost/promovilbackend/index.php?/Comercial/getTar/&draw=2&columns%5B0%5D%5Bdata%5D=Empresa&etc&etc
```

i tryed with `$_GET['draw']` into the function getTar but they return undefined.

any idea?

Comment: try to change getTar/&draw=2 **to** getTar?draw=2

Comment: i'll try, but i'll find this part into the plugin

Comment: it's work! Thx for this.

Comment: please check and up-vote the answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to change `getTar/&draw=2` to `getTar?draw=2`